# Javascript Function not Working Like I Want

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple javascript function that autopopulates a $ amount textbox when 2 options are selected - Regional Council and Member Type. The page is at https://receivers.org/join.htm. I am not done with the complete function, but have functionality for the first 3 Regional Council selections as well as the Regular Member option - the combination of these 2 options determine the $ textbox for Regular Member. It works first time when I select the Regional Council and select the Regular Member option. But when I select any of the two other Regional Councils, the $ textbox does not change to what it is supposed to. I have to click the Regular Member option again for it to populate the correct amount. Here is the function:

```js
function determinePrice() {
  if ((document.getElementById("BA").checked == true) && (document.getElementById("Regular").checked == true)) {
    (document.getElementById("RegularAmt").value = "$105.00");
  } else if ((document.getElementById("CC").checked == true) &&
    (document.getElementById("Regular").checked == true)) {
    (document.getElementById("RegularAmt").value = "$90.00");
  } else if ((document.getElementById("LAOC").checked == true) &&
    (document.getElementById("Regular").checked == true)) {
    (document.getElementById("RegularAmt").value = "$195.00");
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can have the price change if I change Council selections without having to click the Regular option again? The Regular $ values should be for:
Bay Area Council $105
Central California Council $90
Los Angeles/Orange County Council $195

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Call the function from a `change` event listener on the Regional Council radio buttons.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Add `onclick="determinePrice()"` to all the other Regional Council radio buttons.

Comment: Thanks Barmar...how stupid of me. I forgot the onclick code for the other 2. Thanks for pointing that out